# Can I combine image objects without canvas?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas

Is there any way to take 2 or more images and combine them into one image object. With the 2 images appearing side by side so the final image is twice the size? Without using a canvas?

**A bit of context as to why I can't use a canvas:**
I'm making a web app for my iPad pro, perhaps it'll be a hybrid app with phoneGap or Cordova or whatever someday, but right now it's just for me. basically it's a drawing app. one of the features is that the paper size can be infinite (or at least very big). so I can draw, pan over, draw some more, pan, draw, and have a large drawing in the end.

The problem I'm running into is that the iPad's resolution is 2732 × 2048 px, so it only takes 3 or 4 screen lengths before the canvas gives out from being too big. I thought about making a workaround that uses an array of canvases, so it can be a grid of canvases that make up the whole image. which I think would work well within the app, but I'd like to be able to download the completed image as one file. which means I'd need to recombine them, and I can't use a canvas because it'd potentially be too big.

Yes, I realize those are getting to be ridiculous resolutions. And that I might just have to limit my drawing to 8000 x 8000 px or something like that. which might be fine for 95% of situations anyway.

**Edit:** after more testing, it seems dependant on the area of the canvas, so a long skinny image might be 8000px long. but if I limit it to a square size, the biggest stable size is only 4000x4000 which is only like 50% bigger than the iPads width.

thanks!

Comment: So... is your question just if two images can be placed next to each other using CSS?

Comment: no. I want to combine them into one single image, one that can be downloaded as a single .png file

Comment: When it comes to recombining your canvases perhaps you could look into creating an algorithm that properly combines the [imageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) and then use a library such as [pngjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pngjs) to convert it to a png. Unfortunately no matter how you do this, there's no way it's not gonna be a little slow.

Comment: So maybe I could use node.js for the task. Since the various images will get saved to a server anyways. I don't mind it being slow, since it's just during the download that it needs to do this. It can stay as divided images while still in the app.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain or where you thinking I should create a function that uses the `createImageData()` method to combine the data from two canvases? I'm assuming a bigger image can be made that way? and then use pngjs to convert that imageData to a png.

Comment: I was suggesting what's in your second comment, but rather you should use `getImageData` on each canvas and combine them into one signle array. It doesn't have to be an ImageData object, I think a standard array should work so there's no need to use `createImageData`. I would suggest getting the image data from each canvas then using a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to combine each image. Then feed that to pngjs.
I don't think anyone's attempted this before, so I hope you don't run into any unsolvable errors.

Comment: Ah, very interesting. that seems like it should work. it seems like the limitations of a regular array and pngjs are very high, so I don't see it having errors from the size.